# How to compare the tracked files which have been modified and not `add`ed yet with a specific remote branch?

Tags: git

How to compare the tracked files which have been modified and not `add`ed  yet with a specific remote branch?

In other words, I create a commit, and modify some tracked files, but `git add` has not been invoked. I want to see the differences between the modified files and a specific remote branch.

Note: the aforementioned remote branch is not the upstream branch of the current working branch.

Comment: What about `git diff origin/remote-branch-name`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox As far as I can see, the said command is used to compare two HEAD commits, one is the current branch, and the other one is a remote branch. What I need is to compare the current working area with a specific remote branch

Comment: So you want to compare an untracked file... with what?

Comment: @Paolo Not untracked file. The files are tracked files. But they have not been modified and `git add` has not been invoked.

Comment: Look at the definition of working area that you quoted in your question

Comment: @Paolo Sorry for my poor English. I will update it right now.

Comment: what do you think a remote branch is?

Comment: @evolutionxbox A branch of `pointers` that point to each file.

Comment: Sadly not. A branch is a temporary pointer to a commit. (literally a file with a git commit reference in it)

Comment: @evolutionxbox So it is impossible to achieve the the goal mentioned in the post?

Comment: The question does not make sense. _"I create a commit, and modify some tracked files, but git add has not been invoked"_ - specifically this. --- As for seeing the differences, the command I gave should work

Comment: @evolutionxbox What a surprise! That really works!

Answer (score 1):

A Git repository mainly holds *commits*.  A repository in which you can do new work (a regular repository, i.e., one that is not a so-called *bare* repository) additionally has a working tree, and any Git repository—even a "bare" one—has an additional database storing names, such as branch and tag names, and what Git calls the *index* or *staging area*, but in this case we're not particularly interested in those, so let's concentrate first on the commits.

A *commit*, in Git, is a two-part entity:

- It holds a *full snapshot of every file*, frozen for all time so that you can get it back later if you like.
- It holds some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself: the name and email address of the person who made it, for instance.  (There's more but right now we care mostly about the files anyway.)

Each commit is *numbered*, with a big ugly random-looking hash ID.  Git *needs* the number to find the commit.  Git *needs to find the commit first* to find the saved snapshot, and hence all of the files.  Humans, however, are very bad at working with hash IDs.  So we use *names:* branch and tag names, for instance, and also *remote-tracking names* like `origin/somebranch`.

Each of these names translates, through that additional database of name-to-hash-ID entries, to *one hash ID*.  When you run:

```
git switch somebranch
```

you're telling Git: *Look up the name `somebranch` to get a commit hash ID.  Using that hash ID, find all the files that go with it.  Remove, from my working tree, all the files I had out from some other commit; install, instead, all the files from the new commit I want to use.*  If all of that works, Git then remembers the new branch name (by attaching the special name `HEAD` to it) as your *current branch name*.  The hash ID stored *in* the branch name is the *current commit*.  The files that came *out* of that commit are now in your working tree.<sup>1</sup>

In order to create a *new* commit, you generally have to update Git's *index* aka *staging area*, which you'll do with `git add`.  That's because `git commit` doesn't build the new commit from the *working tree* files.  Instead, it uses the index copy of the files.  We'll skip all the details here since that's not particularly relevant to your question, and move on now:

> In other words, I create a commit, and modify some tracked files, but `git add` has not been invoked. I want to see the differences between the modified files and a specific remote branch.

The phrase *remote branch* is tricky here.  People who use it don't always know what *they* mean, and people reading it where someone else has used it assume one thing and it turns out they meant another entirely.  So let's avoid it, and talk instead about *remote-tracking names* like `origin/somebranch`.

Git mostly deals in commits: Git is all about *commits*, with files just sort of coming along for the ride, much of the time.  Every Git repository has its two main databases: the big one full of commits and other supporting Git objects, and a (usually much smaller) second one full of things like branch names.

When we *clone* some Git repository, we're saying to our Git software: *Go read all the **commits** out of some other repository and copy them to my own repository.  Also, see what branch names they have.  Create or update, in my repository, remote-tracking names to remember each hash ID they stored in each of their branch names.*  So, if in their repository—whoever they are, over at `origin`—they have a branch `zorg`, we get an `origin/zorg` that remembers the hash ID of the commit *they* have as their `zorg`.

Again, this is all based on the *commits*.  *Every* commit has a *unique* hash ID, so all of their commits that we copied have their unique hash IDs.  When we make new commits of our own, ours get unique hash IDs too, and all the IDs are always unique, so any one ID always works to find exactly one commit.  (This is where the distributed magic of Git comes from.)

Normally, we might compare entire commits:

```
git diff <hash-ID-of-commit-X> <hash-ID-of-commit-Y>
```

Git will compare *all the files* in the two commits, one file-pair at a time.  We don't have to use raw hash IDs though:

```
git diff br1 br2
```

uses the two branch names, `br1` and `br2`, to find the two raw hash IDs, and compares the files in those two commits.  This even works with remote-tracking names:

```
git diff br1 origin/zorg
```

just translates the two names, even though one of them is a remote-tracking name; they translate to hash IDs of commits in *our* repository.  The hash ID of `origin/zorg` may be the hash ID of a commit we got *from* some other repository, but it's in *our* repository now, and that's what we use.  There's no remote anything happening!

So, knowing all this now, let's get back to your question again:

> I want to see the differences between the modified files and a specific remote branch.

We might not be able to look at a "remote branch", whatever that is, but we *can* look at any *commit* we have.  If our `origin/zorg` *name* finds the right commit, we just need to use that *name* to find the files—*all* the files—that are in that commit.

But we don't want to compare *committed* files to that commit.  So: if we have modified files, and want our Git to compare them to our *current* commit, we just run `git diff HEAD` and that's what `git diff` does for us.  The reason it does that is because we said to use `HEAD` for one of the commits, and `git diff` *automatically* uses *our files*—our *working tree* files, the copies that aren't in Git—as the other set.  The `HEAD` files go on the left side of the `git diff`, and our working tree files go on the right.

This works fine for *other commits too*.  We run:

```
git diff origin/zorg
```

and Git looks up `origin/zorg` to get a commit hash ID and compares *all the files in that commit* (put on the left) to *all the files in our working tree* (put on the right).  The diff output is a set of instructions that would change those files (on the left) into our files (on the right).

What if we want the commit to show the instructions that would change *our* files to *those* files?  That is, we want ours "on the left" and theirs "on the right".  We have to use the `-R` (reverse) diff option, so that's how we do that.

What if we want not to see *every* file, but only a few specific named files?  The answer is: we do the same thing we'd do for any of our commits:

```
git diff [-R] origin/zorg -- file1 file2
```

The `--` separates file names from `git diff` options and arguments, and is only *required* if some of our file names resemble branch names or other such things, but it's a good idea in general.  (Suppose your file is named `foo/bar`.  Do you have a branch or tag named `foo/bar` too?  Are you *sure?*  Put in the `--` and you don't need to be sure: that tells `git diff` that `foo/bar` is a *file* name.)  This form of `git diff` reduces the diff to showing only the named files.

So, overall, that's your answer:

```
git diff <remote-tracking-name> -- <file names>
```

Add the `-R` option to taste.  If you think the other repository has new commits, run `git fetch`, which will have your Git call up their Git and get their new commits and put them into your repository and update your remote-tracking-names.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's an exception here in that you can modify some files from some other commit on some other branch, and switch branches and *carry the modified files with you* ... sometimes, but not always.  But if you don't have a "dirty" working tree, the files you'll have after switching are the ones from the commit you just switched *to*, and that's going to be your particular case here.